# Call function twice or more in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, loops, lambda

I use the code below with `lambda` to call function once in a loop, it works but now I am trying to call the function for specific times like 3 times in a loop, I looked for it and found some solutions but they call function for specific times if there is no loop, when I try it in a loop, nothing changes. Is there a efficient way to do this?

This one works in a loop and print only once. I want something like that to do it for 3 times.

```
def once():
    print "Do function once"
    once.func_code = (lambda:None).func_code

once()
```

This code below doesn't change anything and it keeps on printing forever if it is in a loop, if not it works.

```
def repeat_fun(times, f):
    for i in range(times): f()

def do():
    print 'Do function for 3 times'

repeat_fun(3, do)
```

Also adding counter outside the loop helps but I think there should be a better solution for it.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your problem correctly, but your second code snippet runs correctly for me.  I even put `repeat_fun(3, do)` in a loop and ran it, and it ran the number of times I specified and then stopped.  Are you trying to get that behavior with `lambda`?

Comment: I tried it again, it doesn't work in a loop. `while True: repeat_fun(3, do)`, it keeps printing forever. `lambda` solution will be better but any efficient way to do this is ok too.

Comment: 'while True prints forever',  so your problem is that you create an infinite loop that runs forever ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Replace the function with a function that just does nothing?

Comment: @polku I wrote here with simple print but in my code there are two things. One is to print and one is to terminal notification. I want it to keep on printing and loop but notify me 3 times. So it must be in a infinite loop.

Comment: @Will which one does nothing? I am trying to replace `once.func_code = (lambda:None).func_code` with a function which does 3 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should work with a decorator, that makes it clear, what you intend to do:

```
class call_three_times(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count <= 3:
            return self.func(*args, **kw)

@call_three_times
def func():
    print "Called only three times"

func() # prints "Called only three times"
func() # prints "Called only three times"
func() # prints "Called only three times"
func() # does nothing
```

Comment: yes, that's what I was looking for, it works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Why not add a `max` param and then check that `self.count <= self.max` before calling.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use function instead of class:

```
def call_three_times(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.called += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs) if wrapper.called <= 3 else None
    wrapper.called = 0
    return wrapper


@call_three_times
def func():
    print "Called only three times"
```